# add dynamic ID for wp_nav_menu after and before

Tags: menus

I have menu like this:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="buttons-4" title="some_title">
                <a href="[some_url]">[something]</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="buttons-5" title="some_title">
                <a href="[some_url]">[something]</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and I've try this:

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'my-theme-location',
    'menu' => '',
    'container' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => '',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true,
    'before' => '<div class="buttons-%1$s" title="some_title">',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after' => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

I need every element inside menu item can have class [or ID is also okay] dynamicly like class="buttons-5" and other class="button-6" an so on just like my example. How can I get dynamicly my buttons class? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.   As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: thanks @engelen, sorry for my unclear question. Little bit better for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){
  $output = '<div class="buttons-'.$item->ID.'" title="some_title">';
  $output .= $item_output;
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el' , 10, 4 );
```

This uses `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter to add custom content before and after the link item. `ID` is appended to `buttons-`. If you need this customization for only specific menu then you can check `$args` as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nilambar. It works!. This is my last code:

```
 $menu_middle_left = array(
            'theme_location' => 'middle-left',
            'menu' => '',
            'container' => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'container_id' => '',
            'menu_class' => '',
            'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu()
        );

        wp_nav_menu($menu_middle_left);
```

I put your code in my functions.php:

```
function custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){
  $output = '<div class="buttons-'.$item->ID.'" title="some_title">';
  $output .= $item_output;
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'custom_walker_nav_menu_start_el' , 10, 4 );
```